# something about gulp configuration

Tags: gulp

I was told that "can't find config file:. jshintrc" when I was trying to use gulp.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O57tV.png)

What's wrong? I suppose I have already installed the 'gulp-jshint'

Answer (score 0):

Installing the plugin is not enough, you need to provide a configuration file, this is used by the plugin to understand how you want it to lint your code.

Check out [this example](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank u 4 ur help bro.

Comment: That's what we are here for. Regards!